# Should we change the Linux tag instructions to match community use?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [Linux tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info) instructions state:

> LINUX QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior, not just because you happen to run your code on Linux.

In spite of those instructions, [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tagged question are frequently not about Linux APIs or Linux specific behavior. I sampled the [20 newest questions tagged `linux`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux?tab=Newest), which could be categorized as follows:

- 6 shell scripting, not Linux specific
- 3 administration, specific to particular distribution or container system
- 2 general programming, not Linux API specific, but happen to be running on Linux
- 2 Using a 3rd party software package on Linux
- 2 Linux usage question (where is a core dump, accessing man pages)
- 5 Linux API (including 1 glibc question, which wasn't really specific to Linux)

That is, 75-80% of the questions in the sample did not follow the [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) instructions.

Should we change [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) instructions to match community use, and introduce tag(s) (e.g. [linux-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-api)) for Linux API questions?

Comment: The problem with the linux tag is that nobody enforces that use. It may need a warning the same way of SQL.

Comment: FYI; in meta votes are sometimes used to express disagreement with a post (besides the usual meaning). That could explain some of the downvoting on this question.

Answer (score 7):

The tag is not only about using Linux APIs, but about *"behaviour that's specific to Linux"*, and the tags you propose deal exclusively with "Linux programming/APIs".

In the "general programming" and/or "shell scripting" questions, the [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag could be appropriate (haven't checked, though).

And some of the other cases you list seem to be questions that could simply be off-topic for SO, I don't know how creating another tag would save us from those. The only solution in these situations is vote-to-close in the appropriate manner.

Users misapply tags all the time. I would imagine the Linux tag is far from being the worst example.

Other users with over 2k reputation can fix that in a second, luckily.

No matter what tags are created nor what guidance do they have, they will be misused and will need to be corrected.

Remember to use your full editing privileges when you find those.

Comment: No. Linux non-api is way too general to be a good tag. That's like using a Windows tag just because you use powershell or the winapi. Shell scripting (bash, zsh or any other) aren't exclusive to *NIX OS, they also reside on CygWin, GitBash, MSYS, etc. Nowadays, it's more useful to have tags that describe the specific part you are working with, instead of the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is a meta tag.

Shell scripting can be shell-specific (e.g. [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash), [fish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish), [zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zsh), [ksh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ksh), [tcsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tcsh)), and is not necessarily married to Linux any more.

Linux system administration and usage has always been off-topic and would be better suited on either Unix & Linux or Server Fault, depending on what they're doing.

So, my vote would be to get rid of it.

Comment: For me, rather than meta, it's just too broad and ambiguous.

Comment: @Braiam:  Hence, "meta tag".  It's a well-defined concept.

Comment: Last time I discussed semantics about this thing, I was pointed out to this blog post https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/. I recommend you to read it again. Sometimes we misremember stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doubting me here, @Braiam.  You can't use [tag:linux] as the only tag on a question and have it be truly on-topic.  Additionally, Linux can mean different things to different people, especially given the differences in actual distros (Clear Linux, SuSE, Ubuntu, Debian, RHEL), different runtime environments (VMs or containers), and the nuances in-between all of those things.

Comment: "You can't use linux as the only tag on a question and have it be truly on-topic" that's just a litmus test. Something to easily identify one of these. Meta tag is defined as tags tat "do not describe the content of the question". Linux describe the content of the question. Also are subsets of dependent tags that "don’t say anything by themselves". Linux fails at both levels. I don't doubt you, I'm just trying to tell you that you may be wrong about this one.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Just saying your question is about Linux introduces at **least** two new questions.  I'm not sure why you've elected to go through this with a fine-toothed comb when the point I'm making is crystal clear.

Comment: What about using Linux programming APIs, such as `linux/*.h` in C? It may not be stand-alone, but how many tags are?

Comment: @JL2210:  The preliminary Googling of the `linux/` header space turned up a few interesting and already existing questions about it, most of which could survive *without* the Linux tag.  Of the few that could remain, perhaps something more explicit to describe what the scope of the question really is would help - since `linux/` headers are meant for internal kernel programming, perhaps [tag:linux-kernel] would be best for those.

Comment: @Makoto That's more about drivers and kernel modules than the userspace API. Ahem - *"Questions about writing userspace code in Linux should generally be tagged [linux] instead."*

Comment: @JL2210:  What if I told you that, in light of recent developments, that the tag advice could actually be wrong?

Comment: @Makoto I wouldn't believe you. I currently do not see a problem in the tag advice of either tags. If they were enforced properly, then the issue would be solved.